# Does wearing a topper change your hitbox?

Tags: rocket-league

I was just wondering if I put on a topper if it changes my hit box at all? Or if different toppers have more of a benefit over others?

Comment: I don't think hats make a difference, but I feel it's worth nothing that different vehicles seem to have different hitboxes (based on what I've seen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't. It's only cosmetic.

Comment: ...and you know this how?

Comment: @atticae if you look closly while hitting the ball with a big topper, the hat disappears into the ball.

Answer (score 17):

Picture Evidence that the topper doesn't change the hitbox.

[image]

Equipped the tallest topper I have.

[image]

Flipped the car over. When the car is upside down, the top of the hitbox is resting against the field, and this shows that the hat is purely cosmetic.